# Understanding TextInputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to Hadoop and currently in the process of designing my MapReduce application. In my scenario, I have a csv file. I wish to average each row in the csv file such that a separate mapper is created for each row. As I understand it, TextInputFormat will automatically split the file by line. Am I to understand then, that a separate mapper will be created for each row automatically as well? If not, how do tell Hadoop to do what I want? Do I have to implement a custom splitter? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured it out. I need to use NLineInputFormat.